# Cannot --init the PHP BDD test software 'Behat' on RedHat RHEL/CentOS/Fedora 6.4

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, integration-testing, behat

I have a Vagrant-controlled VirtualBox downloaded from `developer.nrel.gov` running CentOS 6.4

My Puppet `init.pp` file contains:

```
package { "php":
  ensure => "5.3.3-22.el6"
}
```

I am using Composer to install dependencies for my PHP web application, which include Behat and Mink:

```
{
    ...
    "require-dev": {
        "behat/behat": "2.4.*",
        "behat/mink": "1.4.*",
        "behat/mink-extension": "@dev",
        "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "@dev",
        "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "@dev"
    },
    ...
}
```

When running `./bin/behat --init` I get one of the following error messages:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'DOMDocument' not found in .../symfony/config/Symfony/Component/Config/Util/XmlUtils.php on line 47
```

or:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function Behat\Behat\DependencyInjection\mb_internal_encoding() in .../behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/DependencyInjection/BehatExtension.php on line 54
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOMDocument is part of the "DOM" PHP extension. If you compile PHP from source, this gets included by default. Enterprise Linux-based systems require more than just the `php` module to be installed to get a full PHP installation. The second error is caused by a missing multi-byte string module. You can install these manually without having to recompile PHP. To do this using Puppet, add the following to your `init.pp` file:

```
package { "php-mb":
  ensure => "5.3.3-22.el6"
}
package { "php-xml":
  ensure => "5.3.3-22.el6"
}
```

Where the version numbers match the version of PHP you already have installed. This is equivalent to:

```
yum -y install php-mb php-xml
```

Behat will now initialise and run without error.

Comment: With php 5.5 the command would be `yum -y install php55w-mbstring php55w-xml`. Just as a note